# Number of elements in a nested sublist (starting from the first Index)

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

My code is as follows :

```
Nums=[['D'],['A','B'],['A','C'],['C','A']] 


Output should be D=0
                 A=2
                 C=1
                 B=0
```

I have tried as follows:

```
nums=[['D'],['A','B'],['A','C'],['C','A']]
d=dict()
for i  in (nums):
 for j in i:
     if(len(i)==1):
         d[j]=0
     else:
         d[j]=1
print(d)
```

Am I on the right path to choose a dictionary to count the path?
 Please post your suggestion in any data-structure

Comment: I don't understand the desired output. Are you saying that the first element of a sublist should be counted iff it has other elements behind it in a sublist?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: Can the sublists have more than 2 elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
seen_dict = collections.Counter([x[0] for x in Nums if len(x) > 1])
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a dictionary with the sum minus one of the occurrences you can perform a dictionary comprehension using the library [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter # import library
flat = sum(nums, []) # returns a flat list
count = Counter(flat).items() # counts the elements (returns a dictionary)
result = {c[0]:c[1]-1 for c in count} # dictionary comprehnsion returning the sum minus one
```

Compressed form:

```
result = {c[0]:c[1]-1 for c in Counter(sum(nums, [])).items()}
```

Comment: This will not work if sublists have more than 2 elements.

Comment: See this example. Output should still be `{'D': 0, 'A': 2, 'B': 0, 'C': 1}` but it gets `{'D': 0, 'A': 2, 'B': 0, 'C': 2}` https://rextester.com/XDK77058

Comment: Maybe because I didn't understand what is the real requested output. Here is the sum minus one...

Comment: I'm not saying your code is incorrect, it works fine for the sample data in OPs question. But I've asked OP to clarify.

Comment: No problem Nick!